# „Folgende(s,r)“ und „nächste(s,r)“ mit bestimmtem oder ohne Artikel

Tags: grammar, article

Wie sollte man am besten die Wörter *folgende(s,r)*, *nächste(s,r)* benutzen?

- > Ich habe folgenden Brief an sie geschickt. [Inhalt des Briefes]

  oder

  > Ich habe den folgenden Brief an sie geschickt. [Inhalt des Briefes]
- > Für nächste Woche habe ich geplant …

  oder

  > Für die nächste Woche habe ich geplant …

Gibt es irgendeinen Unterschied dazwischen?

Comment: Willkommen beim StackExchange zur deutschen Sprache. Wenn Du möchstest, kannst Du Dir die [tour] ansehen. Im [help] findest Du auf viele Fragen zur Benutzung eine Antwort. Viel Spaß und Danke für Deine Frage!

Comment: Sollte deine Frage beantwortet worden sein, kannst du diese auch akzeptieren, damit man sieht, dass sie korrekt beantwortet wurde.

Answer (score 2):

Hierbei geht es nur um Formalitäten. Es sind jeweils beide Versionen korrekt.
Im umgangssprachlichen Stil wird meistens auf den Artikel verzichtet. In reiner Textform (Zeitungsartikel etc.) wird die Version mit Artikel bevorzugt.

---

Kleiner Hinweis:

Bei

- > Ich habe folgenden Brief an sie geschickt. [Inhalt des Briefes]

und

- > Ich habe den folgenden Brief an sie geschickt. [Inhalt des Briefes]

wird jeweils "sie" verwendet. In dem Sinn, dass damit eine nicht direkt involvierte Person gemeint ist, (z.B. "das Mädchen") wäre diese Form korrekt. Sollte damit eine Person direkt ansprechen wollen, würde man "Sie" groß schreiben.

- > Ich habe folgenden Brief an Sie geschickt. [Inhalt des Briefes]

ist die Höflichkeitsform von

- > Ich habe folgenden Brief an dich geschickt. [Inhalt des Briefes]

Comment: Grundsätzlich saubere Antwort, allerdings hätte der Hinweis auf *sie/Sie* in einem Kommentar unter der Frage besser Platz gefunden. Hoffentlich findet sich noch jemand, der/die dir einen Upvote geben kann, damit du auch überall kommentieren kannst ;)

Comment: ich meinte "sie" als eine dritte Person.

Answer (score -3):

Es sollte auf jeden Fall die Version mit einem bestimmten Artikel der Version ohne eines Artikel vorgezogen werden.
Im Schriftverkehr ist der bestimmte Artikel angebracht.

Um die Antwort etwas zu präzisieren sollten wir uns weniger die Wörter folgende(s,r), nächste(s,r) ansehen sondern das Nomen, auf das sich der Artikel bezieht.

In diesem Fall "nächste Woche" und "folgenden Brief" 
Beide Nomen werden hier näher bestimmt und erfordern damit einen Artikel.

Ein Nullartikel wird NUR in den folgenden Fällen verwendet:

- Abstrakta (z.B. Wer Kinder haben will, der sollte viel Geld, Zeit und Geduld mitbringen.)
- Anreden und Titeln ohne nähere Bestimmung 
  (Gute Nacht Herr Müller.)
- Berufen ohne nähere Bestimmung (+ Verben "sein" und "werden" und nach "als")
  (Thomas will Arzt werden.)
- Eigennamen ohne nähere Bestimmung
  (Susi küsst Volker. Sandra liebt Berthold.)
- dem Plural des unbestimmten Artikels
  (Hast du einen Stift für mich? Hast du Stifte für mich?)
- Nomen nach Maß-, Gewichts- und Mengenangaben
  (Ich hätte gern eine Tasse Kaffee für meine Frau und für mich ein Glas Bier.)
- nicht zählbaren Stoffen oder Materialien
  (Die Uhr des Professors ist aus reinem Gold.)
- Nationalitäten ohne nähere Bestimmung
  (An unserer Universität studieren Türken, Russen, Amerikaner und Franzosen.)
- Namen von Ländern, Städten und Kontinenten
  (Pedro kommt aus Spanien und Luis aus Mexiko.)
- Sprichwörtern
  (Ohne Fleiß kein Preis.)

Quelle: http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=58

Keiner dieser Fälle trifft hier zu. Ein Nullartikel ist damit meines erachtens nicht angebracht.

Comment: Willkommen beim StackExchange zur deutschen Sprache. Wenn Du möchstest, kannst Du Dir die [tour] ansehen. Im [help] findest Du auf viele Fragen zur Benutzung eine Antwort. Viel Spaß und Danke für Deine Antwort :)

Comment: Die Antwort halte ich für falsch. Irgendwelche Belege oder Quellen?

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Hinweise. Ich habe meine Antwort erweitert und präzisiert.

Comment: Ich finde, dieses Beispiel aus dem Duden widerspricht dir: [_die Premiere ist auf nächste Woche verlegt worden_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verlegen_publizieren_vertagen_verlieren). Hier wird _nächste Woche_ auch ohne bestimmter Artikel verwendet.